# Background Worker will not start after RunWorkerAsync()

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

New to C# - I've pieced together some parts of code from an example project I found online that is close to what I'm trying to accomplish - and it refuses to behave the same way.  So far I've learned a lot and done a lot of tweaking, but this piece continues to elude me and I can't find anything quite the same online.  In the example program, the backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); jumps right to the next part of the program.  In my code, it won't.  I've placed breaks at many different places, and it always stops and seems to hang at RunWorkerAsync().  I think part of the problem is that the way the original author of the example program used the background worker doesn't line up with most of the examples I see online...but it works in the example program when I run it on its own.  What am I missing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace DIPUtil
{
public partial class DIPform : Form
{
    #region Fields
    private string outputDirectory;
    protected string findWhatString = "BEGIN";
    protected string replaceWithText = "FANOODLE";


    #endregion

    #region Background
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the main find and replace operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="worker">The BackgroundWorker object.</param>
    /// <returns>The number of files affected by the replace operation.</returns>
    private int DoFindReplace(BackgroundWorker worker)
    {
        //Initialize the affected count variable
        int filesAffectedCount = 0;

        //Initialize the counter
        int counter = 0;

        //Get all XML files in the directory
        string[] filesInDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(outputDirectory, "*.txt");

        //Initialize total file count
        int totalFiles = filesInDirectory.GetLength(0);

        //Analyze each file in the directory
        foreach (string file in filesInDirectory)
        {
            //Perform find and replace operation
            if (FindAndReplace(file))
            {
                //The file was changed so increment variable
                filesAffectedCount++;
            }

            //Increment the counter
            counter++;

            //Report progress
            worker.ReportProgress((int)((counter / totalFiles) * 100.00));
        }

        //Return the total number of files changed
        return filesAffectedCount;
    }
    #endregion

    #region FindAndReplace
    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the find and replace operation on a file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">The path of the file to operate on.</param>
    /// <returns>A value indicating if the file has changed.</returns>
    private bool FindAndReplace(string file)
    {
        //holds the content of the file
        string content = string.Empty;

        //Create a new object to read a file
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            //Read the file into the string variable.
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //Get search text
        string searchText = GetSearchText(findWhatString);

        //Look for a match
        if (Regex.IsMatch(content, searchText))
        {
            //Replace the text
            string newText = Regex.Replace(content, searchText, replaceWithText);

            //Create a new object to write a file
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                //Write the updated file
                sw.Write(newText);
            }

            //A match was found and replaced
            return true;
        }

        //No match found and replaced
        return false;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Various
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the text to find based on the selected options.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textToFind">The text to find in the file.</param>
    /// <returns>The text to search for.</returns>
    private string GetSearchText(string textToFind)
    {
        //Copy the text to find into the search text variable
        //Make the text regex safe
        string searchText = Regex.Escape(findWhatString);

        return searchText;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the properties of the controls prior to beginning the download.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeProcess()
    {
        //Get sources
        outputDirectory = txtDirectory.Text;

        //Set properties for controls affected when replacing
        statuslabel.Text = "Working...";
        progbar.Value = 0;
        progbar.Visible = true;
        btnprocess.Enabled = false;
        btncancel.Enabled = true;

        //Begin downloading files in background
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the properties of the controls after the download has completed.
    /// </summary>
    private void DeinitializeProcess()
    {
        //Set properties for controls affected when operating
        statuslabel.Text = "Ready";
        progbar.Visible = false;
        btnprocess.Enabled = true;
        btncancel.Enabled = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Displays the directory browser dialog.
    /// </summary>
    private void BrowseDirectory()
    {
        //Create a new folder browser object
        FolderBrowserDialog browser = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        //Show the dialog
        if (browser.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Set the selected path
            txtDirectory.Text = browser.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates that the user input is complete.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A value indicating if the user input is complete.</returns>
    private bool InputIsValid()
    {
        //Set the error flag to false
        bool isError = false;

        //Clear all errors
        errorProvider.Clear();

        //Validate the directory name
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDirectory.Text))
        {
            errorProvider.SetError(txtDirectory, "This is a required field.");
            isError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //check to make sure the directory is valid
            if (Directory.Exists(txtDirectory.Text) == false)
            {
                errorProvider.SetError(txtDirectory, "The selected directory does not exist.");
                isError = true;
            }
        }

        //Return a value indicating if the input is valid
        if (isError)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Events
    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a work object and initialize
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        //Run the find and replace operation and store total files affected in the result property
        e.Result = (int)DoFindReplace(worker);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Update the prog bar
        progbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //The background operation is done
        DeinitializeProcess();

        //Perform final operations
        if (e.Error != null)
            MessageBox.Show(this, e.Error.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        else if (e.Cancelled)
            MessageBox.Show(this, "The operation was ended by the user.", "Cancelled.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        else
            MessageBox.Show(this, string.Format("{0} files were updated by the operation.", e.Result.ToString()), "Replace Complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
    public DIPform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DIPform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnprocess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Verify input is ok
        if (InputIsValid())
            InitializeProcess();
    }

    private void btncancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //private void linkbrowse_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    // {
        //Select a directory to output files
    //    BrowseDirectory();
    //}
    private void linkbrowse_LinkClicked_1(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Select a directory to output files
        BrowseDirectory();
    }
    #endregion



}
}
```

Comment: Did you place the BackgroundWorker onto the form via the Form Designer? Because you should... if you didn't, go back and add it via the designer.

Comment: where do you set the `backgroundWorker.DoWork` event?

Comment: Yes, it is added to the form in the form designer.

Comment: If you add the bgw via the form designer, the event handlers are done for you.  If you programmatically add a bgw, then you must also programmatically add the event handler.

Comment: DoWork event is in Events region (line 209 in my editor)

Comment: @hispeedzintarwebz: is that event *actually hooked up* in the designer?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - what do you mean by actually hooked up?

Comment: as in is the event handler pointing to your method correctly in order to execute when `RunWorkerAsync()` is called.

Comment: @hispeedzintarwebz: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwwsdtbk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MatthewWatson - placing it through the designer only increases the chances of forgetting or (accidentally) losing eventhandlers. It adss little and is certainly not required.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - this makes sense.  I assumed having matching names would in and of itself take care of things being "wired up."  Works perfectly now.  Thank you for taking the time to help.  One more thing in the "I've learned this today" list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `RunWorkerAsync()`, the event `DoWork` is raised. When this happens, the method that was added to this event will be executed:

`backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);`

`private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {/...}`

Check your designer and see if it is wired up correctly.

See here for more information:

[BackGround Worker Class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The backgroundworker.DoWork += new..... line - does that go in the public DIPform() section under InitializeComponent()?  I've seen it there in examples, but it didn't fix my issue and wasn't in the original example code either.

Comment: place that directly under `InitializeComponent();` in the constructor.

Comment: Added this - as well as looked at the link above (which somehow I never found in all my searching on MSDN regarding BackgroundWorker) and "wired" the element on the form to the events in the code.  Never knew about the lightning bolt in the properties browser.  Much thanks to you and @MichaelPerrenoud.

Comment: The "lightning bolt" is good, but it can sometimes be missed if you are looking through the code in the future and can't work out what is going on. this is more explicit and readable.

Answer (score -3):

What Do You expect ? If You place Your background worker on the form via designer and wire up the eventhandlers, AND then manually assign a new reference to this ( as You have done) by creating a new one, the value of the reference inside the variable changes, and there is now another reference inside the variable, as which the eventlisteners were attached to previously. You do not need to create an new BackroundWorker, If You dragged it onto the form with the designer. If You do evrtything by code, than You need to instantiate, attach the listeners manually, etc.... both ways are partially exclusive ways of how to deal with that, You can mix them, only If You have a clear view...